# Cisco packer tracer training - exercise 2.1.1.5

Tags: cisco, wireless, modem

I’m currently starting Cisco and using the packet tracer course, but I’m having an issue with a section creating a simply topology. Everything good apart from one thing which is from wireless router to cable modem I’m using copper straight wire and when I connect router with internet interface to modem port 1 as required the connection is red. All devices are configured correctly and green linked.[image]Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sadly, education and examination questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably picked the wrong router type. 
Try to replace it by the WRT300N model. I've been stuck also on this one few days ago :)

Cannot tell you technically why the first HomeRouter model behave this way though as I'm not yet enough experienced!

Comment: Thanks a lot , I’ve also been puzzled by this for few days, but as I’m new, you don’t automatically see that model in device selection, I had to search for it. Much appreciated 